# asp.gridview full row select not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I know this already answered several times. but after I checked my code against many of then and it is not working I had to ask for help.

my aspx code:

```
 <asp:GridView CssClass="filled" ID="gvuMsgBox" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="msgID" GridLines="Both" 
      PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" PagerSettings-PageButtonCount="10">
```

my rowDataBoundEvent event:

```
Protected Sub gvuMsgBox_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvuMsgBox.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.textDecoration='underline';")
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.textDecoration='none';")
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:alert( '" & FormatURL(CInt(CType(e.Row.Cells(0).FindControl("litId"), Literal).Text)) + "');")
    End If
End Sub
```

FYI I used zurb foundation javascript and css codes for responsive stuff.
Also checked Attributes collection while tracing and everything is Ok. 
Used firebug and can't find any trace of these attributes things in browser !?! 
and No effect on my gridView. no row hilighting and no alerting :(

Any Idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I give up and moved to other urgent work. Now I had some time to work on this issue and found the problem source. So it may help others.
the program I am working on, has some cssproviders that I missed.
the cssproviders prevent my applied code to work so I changed the cssproviders the way I need them and now everything is working fine.

Luck

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```vb
 Protected Sub gvuMsgBox_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvuMsgBox.RowDataBound
        If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;")
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.textDecoration='underline';")
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.textDecoration='none';")
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:alert( '" & FormatURL(CInt(CType(e.Row.Cells(0).FindControl("litId"), Literal).Text)) + "');")
        End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, not working. as before the code runs fine and attributes collection is filled with what we want. but no effect.

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0T083d2VmaFVlV00/edit?usp=sharing)'s the link to my test project. It is working fine in FF, Chrome, IE and Opera.

Comment: thanks man, I know your code is working, mine is working in a normal project too. I have a responsive theme with bunch of css/js as I mentioned in my question (foundation). i doe not sure about mixture I can't see my dynamic styles in rendered HTML via firebug. I need a solution to track them and dont find it yet

Comment: I believe even after adding all your javascript libraries, these pure javascript functions should work well. Probably you did not post your non-working code, which probably implements function from the libraries you have added.

Comment: thanks for reply, what I was posted is my not working code. I replaced it with yours and nothing has changed. as I said the gvuMsgBox_RowDataBound is running perfectly. I checked the page with firebug and I can't see any trace of onmouseover... in it.

Comment: If you send me your project, I can take a look. Else it is hard to guess why it is not working for you.

Comment: thanks man, sending my project is not allowed for me. but i'll try to make a sample to simulate the problem in next week.

Comment: I found the source of the problem it was a previously css-adapter that handles gridview. thanks afzalulh